# When rep is changed from user removal, have landing page explaining why

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

I want the "user was removed" message to take me to the [user removal explanation FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

### Actual

[image: No explanation link for user removal rep change]

Normally when my rep changes, I can click an item in my achievements dialog and it will take me to the question/answer where my rep got changed.

If I click on an entry "user was removed", it takes me to my [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134572/alexander-bird). It does not take me to any page explaining what's happening. I had to google it to figure out what on earth was going on.

### Requested

When I click on the entry highlighted in the screenshot, I would like it to take me to the [user removal explanation FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

Comment: But on [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10608/alexander-bird?tab=reputation), there is an entry for "user was removed", with a link to that FAQ page.

Comment: I want it to take me to the question/answer I lost rep on.

Comment: @gunr2171: First, usability experience matters in its own terms. Technical accessibility to that information is not the drive for the question. And second: it wasn't visible on my main profile page because there were enough other rep changes that the user removal item wasn't visible there. I have to first navigate to my reputation page, then order by time before I even see that particular link.

Comment: @Simon: First, that's not possible because there is often not one Q/A wherein some loses rep. There could be many, many questions/answers. Second, if that was the behavior, I still would have no idea that I lose rep from a user deletion. If I see a question page, I won't think "I bet some guy had his account deleted". As a user, my [mental model](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mental-models/) must be educated before anything else I see will make sense.